# Cascading delete on table that references itself

Tags: t-sql, ef-code-first

I have a table (say 'MyTable') that can reference itself, ie. it has a ParentId that can point to another record in the same table (so you can store a tree of related nodes).

The problem is that when I try to delete all records that are children of a specific parent, I get the following exception (using EF 6):

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.MyTable_dbo.MyTable_ParentId". The conflict occurred in database "foo", table "dbo.MyTable", column 'ParentId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

(I'm executing a Sql command like this `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [MyTable] WHERE ParentId = {0}", parentId);`

I  tried to fix it by adding a Children property and use fluent api to set cascading delete like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
.HasMany(t => t.Children)
.WithOptional(t => t.Parent)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But that gives the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.MyTable_dbo.MyTable_ParentId' on table 'MyTable' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Also when I manually remove the FK and recreate it with ON CASCADE DELETE I get the same error.

I'm a bit lost now on how to fix this.. so any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: If it were me, I would put the delete statements into a stored procedure and call that from your application.  So the logic to find the parent and all related children would be in t-sql procedure.  If I get a few more minutes I can help you with that approach if that is something you would consider.

Comment: Do you receive any errors when running the query in ssms?

Comment: @JasonByrd errors in SSMS are the same (that's what I used when doing it manually)

Comment: @Jesse I already have implemented a workaround now (I can determine the children by looking at a combination of values in others columns in the table. not too pretty, but for now it works.)

Comment: Glad you got it working. I tried to reproduce the problem but received no error.

Answer (score 0):

USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employees') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #Employees;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Employees
(
  empid   INT          PRIMARY KEY,
  mgrid   INT          NULL REFERENCES #Employees,
  empname VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unc_mgrid_empid ON #Employees(mgrid, empid);

INSERT INTO #Employees(empid, mgrid, empname) VALUES
  (1,  NULL, 'David'),
  (2,  1,    'Eitan'),
  (3,  1,    'Ina'),
  (4,  2,    'Seraph'),
  (5,  2,    'Jiru'),
  (6,  2,    'Steve'),
  (7,  3,    'Aaron'),
  (8,  5,    'Lilach'),
  (9,  7,    'Rita'),
  (10, 5,    'Sean'),
  (11, 7,    'Gabriel'),
  (12, 9,    'Emilia'),
  (13, 9,    'Michael'),
  (14, 9,    'Didi');
GO

DELETE FROM #Employees WHERE mgrid = 9
SELECT * FROM #Employees;